# PHP driver printing insufficient memory error

Tags: php, printing, serial-port, out-of-memory, driver

When I try to use run the code below I get the following error:

com_exception: **Source:** mscorlib
**Description:** Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.

```
  $this->TSC = new COM ("TSCSDK.driver");
        $this->TSC->openport ("NAMEOFPRINTER01");
        $this->TSC->sendcommand("SIZE 50 mm, 30 mm");
        $this->TSC->sendcommand("DIRECTION 1");
        $this->TSC->windowsfont(10, 20, 30, 0, 0, 0, "arial", "{$text}");
        //repeat printing line several times.
        $this->TSC->closeport();
```

I am using a TSC printer. I downloaded the driver from their website https://www.tscprinters.com/EN/support. And I had to use a registry hack (https://techtalk.gfi.com/32bit-object-64bit-environment/) to make it work since the driver was for 32-bit windows and I am using 64-bit windows.

This error usually starts happening after I print a few times. Then it keeps happening every time for a while, then goes away randomly. I was wondering if it is a bug with the driver? Should I switch to printing to pdf instead? The only problem with printing to pdf is that I potentially need to print hundreds or even thousands of labels at a time. I'm not sure if libraries like FPDF or MPDF can handle it. I was thinking of using TC-PDF but the library seems to have been almost abandoned.

Please give me your opinion, even if you don't know the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to run the example which is given on site, but it is not working and showing ```Failed to create COM object `TSCSDK.driver': Class not registered``` can you help me? link : https://fs.tscprinters.com/en/dl/1/3378

Comment: Did you already follow the steps in https://techtalk.gfi.com/32bit-object-64bit-environment/ ? It says "Trying to access a 32bit COM in a 64bit environment will result in a class not registered error"

Comment: i have checked those steps but, not able to replicate in my system I am not clear with those steps.

Comment: Sorry, I only know that those steps worked for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this line:

```
$this->TSC->windowsfont(10, 20, 30, 0, 0, 0, "arial", "{$text}");
```

I changed it to send a native TSCPL command (sendcommand instead of windowsfont), and it didn't give the issue anymore.

```
$this->TSC->sendcommand("TEXT {$x},{$this->currentYPosition},\"0\",0,{$fontSize},{$fontSize},\"{$text}\"");
```